# Python - Unit testing functions that are dependant on previous functions outcome (Chained functions)

Tags: python, unit-testing, pytest

I have three inter-dependant `python functions`: f(), g(), and h() such as:

- `g()` depends on the outcome of `f()`.
- `h()` depends on the outcome of `g()`.

```py
def f():
    ...

def g():
    f()
    ...

def h():
    g()
    ...
```

To `unit test` these functions I'm using `py.test`. In the way I'm trying to unit test, I'm observing some redundancy:

```py
def test_f():
    assert f()

def test_g():
    f()
    assert g()

def test_h():
    g()
    assert h()
```

How should I design the `Unit Tests`, in this particular case?

Comment: This sounds more like integration tests than unit tests.  If you want, you should check out the mock library http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/compare.html#mock-chained-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood you correctly, but if i did then you can do

```
def test_functions():
    assert f() 
    assert g() 
    assert h()
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to `unit testing`. Is it a good design to put all the tests inside the `same function`? Actually, what you did is exactly what should be done, but I have doubts about the aggregation of all the unit tests inside the same test function (even though if the `first test` fails, there's no need to perform the `second and third`).

Comment: If the functions truly depends on one another as in -  it doesn't make sense to call g()  without f()  then I honestly think it is OK to put them in the same test, after all, it won't be helpful to see all of them fail just because of one of these functions